# How to post data to Google Sheets from a React Native Android application without a third party service

Tags: react-native, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-api

I'm a react native newbie, and I am currently working on a research project in creating a mobile application for data collection. I have searched far and wide for project samples and tutorials in achieving this, but I am really having a hard time finding one that works without a third-party service :( I just need a way where I can solely use Google Apps Script and the Google Sheets API for my RN project. If anyone here could help me, or better yet have a simple sample project where I can see how to implement the GoogleSheets API in a RN project and how to perform different CRUD methods, I will greatly appreciate it! Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered using a web app.

Comment: I have considered it, however, I'm far too deep into the project, almost completing the front-end of the app haha. The Google Sheets Backend is the only thing missing now.